# jQuery Wrap not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

In the `else if` I'm trying to check if a div has a parent.  Only the first `if` is working, when the parent is modal, the rest are not working.

What have I missed?

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    var width = $(window).width();
    if (width > 767) {
      $('div.modal').contents().unwrap();
      $('div.modal-dialog').contents().unwrap();
      $('div.modal-content').contents().unwrap();
      $('div.modal-header').contents().unwrap();
      $( "form.r-interview" ).addClass( "white-color" );
      $('div.modal-body').contents().unwrap();
    }
    else if ( width == 320 ) {
      if (!$("div.modal-content, .modal-dialog, header.form-header, form.r-interview").parent().hasClass('.modal')) {
        $( "div.modal-content, .modal-dialog, header.form-header, form.r-interview" ).wrapAll( "<div class='modal fade' id='form_modal' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='mySmallModalLabel'></div>" );
      }
      else if (!$("div.modal-content, header.form-header, form.r-intervieww").parent().hasClass('.modal-dialog')) {
        $( "div.modal-content, header.form-header, form.r-interview" ).wrapAll( "<div class='modal-dialog'></div>" );
      }
      else if (!$("header.form-header, form.r-interview").parent().hasClass('.modal-content')) {
        $( "header.form-header, form.r-interview" ).wrapAll( "<div class='modal-content'></div>" );
      }
      else if (!$("header.form-header").parent().hasClass('.modal-header')) {
        $( "header.form-header" ).wrap( "<div class='modal-header'></div>" );
      } 
      else if (!$("form.r-interview").parent().hasClass('.modal-body')) {
        $( "form.r-interview" ).wrap( "<div class='modal-body'></div>" );
        $( "form.r-interview" ).removeClass( "white-color" );
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: You should remove the `.` from your `hasClass` selector: `.hasClass('modal-body')`